# How can I enter the found file finder in Spotlight?

Tags: finder, spotlight

I use Spotlight find my require file see bellow:

[image]

But how can I enter the file's directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> to get there.